# Ggplot code and function with a ggplot do not provide the same result

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

I am having trouble creating a function that includes a ggplot inside. When I execute the code outside the function, it generates the plot I want, but within the function it generates a different plot... I am not sure what I am doing wrong...

I copy below the reprex with an example database:

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 4.0.5
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.0.5
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 4.0.5
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 4.0.5
#> Warning: package 'readr' was built under R version 4.0.5
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 4.0.5
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.0.5
#> Warning: package 'stringr' was built under R version 4.0.5
#> Warning: package 'forcats' was built under R version 4.0.5
library(ggplot2)

# Example data 
wb <- data.frame(country = c("Antigua and Barbuda", "Belize", "Costa Rica", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic",
                             "El Salvador", "Guyana", "Guatemala", "Haiti", "Honduras", "Jamaica", "Nicaragua", 
                             "Panama", "Surinam", "Trinidad and Tobago"), 
                 income = factor(c("high", "low", "upper-middle","upper-middle", "upper-middle", 
                                   "lower-middle", "upper-middle", "upper-middle","low", NA, "upper-middle",
                                   "lower-middle", "high", "upper-middle", "high")),
                 group = c("A", "C", "B","C", "B","B", "B", "C","B", "A", "B","C", "C", "B", "A"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


# I execute  the folowing code to create a plot (I do not execute it now because I do not have enough reputation in the forum to do it): 
df <- wb %>% 
  drop_na(income) %>%
  group_by(group,income) %>% 
  tally() %>% 
  complete(income, fill = list(n = 0)) %>% 
  mutate(percentage = n / sum(n) * 100)

ggplot(df, aes(income, percentage, fill = group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge') +
  scale_y_continuous("Title Y", expand = c(0,0))+ 
  scale_x_discrete("Title X")+ 
  scale_fill_manual("Title of legend", values = c("#15607a", "#18a1cd", "cyan")) +
  theme_classic(base_size=11) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, 
                                   hjust = 1, vjust = 0),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), 
        legend.title = element_text(colour = "#00344c", size = 8, face = "bold"))
```

```r
# Now I try to create a function to automatize the previous plot 

create_graph <- function(x,y,t){
  df <- wb %>% 
    drop_na({{y}}) %>%
    group_by({{x}},{{y}}) %>% 
    tally() %>% 
    complete({{y}}, fill = list(n = 0)) %>% 
    mutate(percentage = n / sum(n) * 100)
  
  ggplot(df, aes(y, percentage, fill = x)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge') +
    scale_y_continuous("Title Y", expand = c(0,0))+ 
    scale_x_discrete(t)+ 
    scale_fill_manual("Title of legend", values = c("#15607a", "#18a1cd", "cyan")) +
    theme_classic(base_size=11) + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, 
                                     hjust = 1, vjust = 0),
          axis.line = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), 
          legend.title = element_text(colour = "#00344c", size = 8, face = "bold")) 
}

# When I execute the function alone, the resulting plot it's not the same as the plot coded above: 
create_graph(x = "income", 
             y = "group",
             t = "Funny title")
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Super thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A couple of observations:

- In the `create_graph()` call, you don't need to quote variable names if you're using the curly-curly `{{..}}` wrapper for non-standard evaluation.
- In the `create_graph()` function, I think you might have swapped around some `x`'s and `y`s relative to your example plot.
- In the `aes(...)` call, you can also use the curly-curly wrapper.

Here is how I got the function to return the sample plot as the example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

# Example data 
wb <- data.frame(country = c("Antigua and Barbuda", "Belize", "Costa Rica", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic",
                             "El Salvador", "Guyana", "Guatemala", "Haiti", "Honduras", "Jamaica", "Nicaragua", 
                             "Panama", "Surinam", "Trinidad and Tobago"), 
                 income = factor(c("high", "low", "upper-middle","upper-middle", "upper-middle", 
                                   "lower-middle", "upper-middle", "upper-middle","low", NA, "upper-middle",
                                   "lower-middle", "high", "upper-middle", "high")),
                 group = c("A", "C", "B","C", "B","B", "B", "C","B", "A", "B","C", "C", "B", "A"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

create_graph <- function(x,y,t){
  df <- wb %>% 
    drop_na({{x}}) %>%
    group_by({{y}},{{x}}) %>% 
    tally() %>% 
    complete({{x}}, fill = list(n = 0)) %>% 
    mutate(percentage = n / sum(n) * 100)
  
  ggplot(df, aes({{x}}, percentage, fill = {{y}})) + 
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge') +
    scale_y_continuous("Title Y", expand = c(0,0))+ 
    scale_x_discrete(t)+ 
    scale_fill_manual("Title of legend", values = c("#15607a", "#18a1cd", "cyan")) +
    theme_classic(base_size=11) + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, 
                                     hjust = 1, vjust = 0),
          axis.line = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), 
          legend.title = element_text(colour = "#00344c", size = 8, face = "bold")) 
}

create_graph(x = income, 
             y = group,
             t = "Funny title")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Side note: if you name your second argument `y`, people might expect that `y` is what appears on the y-axis, whereas this is not the case in your plot.